# iPhone Application Automation Testing

Tags: ios, iphone, testing, automation, automated-tests

I am working on an iPhone application and planning to automate test case (front end only, backend is a REST API and will be automating using Selenium ). As per my understanding selenium can only be used to automate android application and cannot be used for iPhone.

Can anyone please suggest me (help me out with a solution) something like selenium to do the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

appium works well for both iOS and Android. Have you tried that option?
Check this out: http://www.slideshare.net/videotuition/selendroid-vs-appium-mobile-test-automation-frameworks-selenium-web-driver-automation-32158263

Answer (score -1):

a test form, an application IOS using selenium, is a Appium, it is a great tool, runs on both Android and Ios

Comment: would you mind enhancing your answer a bit? Perhaps include some snippet or reference.